# Driver License exam program. cannot convert std:: string to std :: string and other errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am doing a driver license program where the user has to enter a series of answers  that is put into a string then is compared to the real answers and then determines if the user passed or failed. Below is my program and I am receiving numerous errors. I am using C++ in Visual Studios

```
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' line 69
Error   C2664   'void TestGrader::setKey(std::string [])': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::string' to 'std::string []' line 73
Error (active)  E0289   no instance of constructor "std::basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc=std::allocator<char>]" matches the argument list       line 69
Error (active)  E0413   no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "std::string *" exists   line 73
```

Below is the current code I have. 
If someone can explain to me why I am getting these errors and how to fix them that would be really appreciated.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cctype> 

using namespace std;

const int STRING_COUNTER = 20;

class TestGrader 
{
  private:
    string answers[20];

public:
    void setKey(string right[])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < STRING_COUNTER; i++)
        {
            answers[i] = right[i];
        }

    };
    void grade(string exam[])
    {
        int correct = 0;
        int wrong = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < STRING_COUNTER; i++)
        {
            if (exam[i] == answers[i])
            {
                correct += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                wrong += 1;
            }
        }

        if (correct >= 15)
        {
            cout << "You passed the test!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "You failed the test." << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "You got " << correct << " questions right and got " << wrong << " questions wrong." << endl << endl;

        for (int x = 0; x < STRING_COUNTER; x++)
        {
            if (exam[x] != answers[x])
            {
                cout << "You got question number " << x << " wrong.";
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    };

};


int main()
{
    string answer = {     "B","D","A","A","C","A","B","A","C","D","B","C","D","A","D","C","C","B","D","A" };

TestGrader test;

test.setKey(answer);

string stuTest[STRING_COUNTER];

int choice = 1;

do
{
    for (int i = 0; i < STRING_COUNTER; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter your answer for question number " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> stuTest[i];
        cout << endl;

        while (stuTest[i] > "D" || stuTest[i] < "A")
        {
            cout << "Error, only letters A,B,C and D are accepted: ";
            cin >> stuTest[i];
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    test.grade(stuTest);

    cout << "Would you like to Retake the test? 1. Yes 2. No";
    cin >> choice;

} while (choice == 1);


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Error C2440 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::basic_string,std::allocator>' line 69` -
means that you have a list (or an array) that you are trying to initialize the `std::string` with, which is not allowed. A string is a string, not an array of strings.  If the variable was an array it would be ok:

```
string answer[] = {"B","D","A","A","C","A","B","A","C","D","B","C","D","A","D","C","C","B","D","A" };
```

`Error C2664 'void TestGrader::setKey(std::string [])': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::string' to 'std::string []' line 73` - set key expects an array of strings - you are giving it a string - the fix above would fix that.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much. I should've known that simple fix. I can't believe I didn't realize that when I first wrote it.